# Convert GraphResponse to json response

Tags: android, json, facebook

I want to post some message on Facebook and to get the `id` of the post.
Below is my code.

```
 post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message", "This is a test message");
            /* make the API call */
            new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/feed",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        /* handle the result */


                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();               
        }
    });
```

and I get a response like that:

```
{
    Response: { responseCode: 200 },
    graphObject: {"id":"173048733066533_234919673546105"}, 
    error: null
}
```

I need this "id" from `graphObject` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at official Facebook document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/)

If you do an asynchronous **(Request.executeAsync())** request, you'll use a Request.Callback with an **onCompleted(Response response)** method. If you do a request in series (be sure you're not on the main thread), the Response will be the value returned by the **Request.executeAndWait()** method.

From the Response object, you can call **response.getGraphObject().getInnerJsonObject()**

Example:

```
 JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("Facebook error", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
```

I hope it work.

Comment: Thanks.. response.getGraphObject().getInnerJsonObject() it's works

Comment: This is not woriking!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code,

```
 try {
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
    JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("graphObject");
    JSONObject first = results.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject shipper = first.getJSONObject("id");
    String id = shipper.getString("id");
    Log.d("id",id);

}catch (JSONException e){

}
```

Not tested although you can test.